# errors in rake text.I used scaffold to create a db the migrated it with rake it ran with no error but when i started the sever it gave runtime errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, bundle, scaffold

So i ran rake test which gave me following results

7 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 7 errors, 0 skips
** Invoke test:integration (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare
** Execute test:integration
Errors running test:functionals! #

Comment: Post here contents of UsersControllerTest to see your code.

Comment: it is too long to post here (contains 40000 word and the limit is 30000 words)

Comment: So much words for 7 controller tests? I am asking to post 7 tests, which throw those errors.

Comment: yup i first posted those but stackoverflow didnt allow me topost it so i had to cut short it

Comment: so i did post here the first 3 hope you can help me

Comment: @Fash, you don't have to put all of your errors here. 1 or 2 errors will do. And you need to show the test code that fails otherwise we don't know what is causing these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problems were with naming the models.
including those 's' at the end was creating the problem.